# Regex to remove special characters from a Json node

Tags: java, regex, objectmapper, jsonnode

I have a JSON node as below from which I need to remove all the values after # like DynamicAttribute#1279930005#ZZ8400  to  DynamicAttribute

```
{
"uniqueCode": "ZZ",
"entity": "PROFILE",
"id": "e2b627b360d664377b227b--70378143#1",
"data": [
    "DynamicAttribute"
],
"values": {
    "DynamicAttribute#1279930005#ZZ8400": [
        {
            "property": "activeFlag",
            "currentState": true,
            "previousState": null
        }
    ]
},
"DATE_TIME": "05-Apr-2023 19:17:14.376"}
```

What i tried so far was as below :

```
String eventData; //Has the above json payload
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(eventData);
ObjectNode objectNode = objectMapper.convertValue(jsonNode.get("values"), ObjectNode.class);
objectNode.toString().replaceAll("\\#.*", "\":[");
```

But the above is giving me only like below and removing the rest of the fields from json :

"{"DynamicAttribute":["

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are interested in the regex, you can use this: `#\\w+#\\w+` to match (and remove) 2 groups of #abc or something like `#\\d+#\\w+` if the first one is always going to be numeric:

```
@Test
void test() throws JsonProcessingException {
    String eventData = """
        {
            "uniqueCode": "ZZ",
            "entity": "PROFILE",
            "id": "e2b627b360d664377b227b--70378143#1",
            "data": [
                "DynamicAttribute"
            ],
            "values": {
                "DynamicAttribute#1279930005#ZZ8400": [
                    {
                        "property": "activeFlag",
                        "currentState": true,
                        "previousState": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            "DATE_TIME": "05-Apr-2023 19:17:14.376"
        }
        """;

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(eventData);
    ObjectNode objectNode = objectMapper.convertValue(jsonNode.get("values"), ObjectNode.class);

    String json = objectNode.toString().replaceAll("#\\w+#\\w+", "");
    assertEquals(json, "{\"DynamicAttribute\":[{\"property\":\"activeFlag\",\"currentState\":true,\"previousState\":null}]}");
}
```